# haskell hGetLines implementation

Tags: haskell, input, io

Does anyone know where can I find the

```
hGetLine :: Handle -> IO Text
```

function implementation? I have to implement a HTTP server in haskell which has multiple subtasks. The first one is to write the implementation of a

```
hGetLines :: Handle -> IO [Text]
```

function which reads everything from the IO channel until the first empty line and the lines are returned as a list of Text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to know how `hGetLine` is implemented to do this:

```
hGetLines :: Handle -> IO [Text]
hGetLines h = do
  line <- hGetLine h
  if null line
    then return []
    else do
      lines <- hGetLines h
      return (line:lines)
```

Answer (score 6):

1. Find it on Hackage: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/System-IO.html#v:hGetLine
2. Click the "source" link: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/src/GHC-IO-Handle-Text.html#hGetLine
3. Read source:

   ```
   hGetLine h =
     wantReadableHandle_ "hGetLine" h $ \ handle_ -> do
       hGetLineBuffered handle_
   ```

But if you want to write a `hGetLines` function, you don't need to know how `hGetLine` is implemented. You can just use `hGetLine` in your implementation of `hGetLines`.

Comment: Even more so, I don't think `wantReadableHandle_` is really a function you want to be using, so looking at the implementation is completely useless. Do note, however, that he was talking about `hGetLine` from `Data.Text.IO`, not the standard library.

Comment: @alternative You're correct on all accounts! I completely missed the Text type signature. Silly me. Same process applies, though.